# Adding several objects of same type, to XML-file

Tags: xml, powershell

Is there a way to get commands that return several instances of same type object to get stored in each their variable?

It's possible this ain't the best solution. What I'm dooing is gathering information from the computer and then saving it to a xml file.

Take this:

```
gwmi -cn $compname Win32_UserAccount -filter 'LocalAccount=true' | foreach{$_.Name}
```

i want all the results placed in a xml file after this command has run, something like this:

```
$template = @"
<computer version='1.0'>
  <users>
    <user>"HERE"</user>
    <user></user>
  </users
</computer>
"@
```

The tricky thing is that the number of objects will vary from computer to computer, but I want this script to make another `"<user></user>"`  for each object it finds and then place it there.

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: Read this http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2009/02/02/xml-part-2-write-add-and-change-xml-data.aspx too. It's a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do that, you'd have to generate the XML yourself. That said, there are two cmdlets in PowerShell that creates an XML-based representation of an object: `Export-CliXml` and `ConvertTo-Xml`. Check the help for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute code inside a here string which can come in handy:

```
PS> $template = @" 
<computer version='1.0'> 
  <users>$(gwmi -cn localhost Win32_UserAccount -filter 'LocalAccount=true' | foreach {"`n    <user>$($_.Name)</user>"})
  </users>
</computer> 
"@ 

PS> $template

<computer version='1.0'> 
  <users>
    <user>Administrator</user> 
    <user>Guest</user> 
    <user>R1039564</user>
    <user>sysuser</user>
  </users>
</computer>
```